# how to access javascript querystring in codebehind?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

im sending a value from one page in aspx to another page as shown below.

window.location="test1.aspx?id=1"

how to access this value in codebehind or global.asax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could retrieve the id parameter from the `Request` object in your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = Request["id"];
    // do something with the id
}
```

Also you will have to fix your javascript because the url you are assigning is invalid. You have an extra `+` character that should be removed:

```
window.location.href = 'test1.aspx?id=1';
```

Comment: is it possible to access the same in global.asax?

Comment: Global.asax is a file. In which event of this file do you need to access the id query string? You could access it for example in the `Application_BeginRequest` event.

Comment: @user1357872: You can access anything from the `Request` object anywhere that the `HttpContext` is in scope.  Take a look at `System.Web.HttpContext.Current`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.current.aspx

Comment: yes. I need to access that in application_BeginRequest event. please explain how to access the same javascript variable in global.asax?

Comment: @David, that's not true. `System.Web.HttpContext.Current` is a static object that you could access everywhere. But obviously it makes no sense to access it for example in Application_Start when running in integrated pipeline mode as there's no HttpContext at all. All you will get is an exception. Same stands true for background threads where there's no HttpContext.

Comment: @user1357872, you could access it like this: `string id = HttpContext.Current.Request["id"];`.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: That's what I mean by "in scope" (though I could have been more clear to the OP, for sure).  If the object is set and populated (basically, if we're currently in the scope of a request/response within the web application), then it's accessible.

Comment: Also i would like to know is it possible to access a javasript variable in global.asax?

Answer (score 1):

Leave the `+` sign out and use the `Request.QueryString` object.

```
window.location="test1.aspx?id=1"

string v = Request.QueryString["id"];
```